# C# Single File WASM Bundle

Tags: c#, .net, webassembly

Currently when [generating WASM from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop?view=aspnetcore-7.0), the resulting "bundle" consists of about 20 different files when building with `dotnet publish`:

[image]

Is there a way to get dotnet to generate just a single `dotnet.min.js` bundle file so that it's easier to distribute?

Comment: Is it not sufficient to just have your build server just zip the output? Web applications are typically distributed to the end user over a webserver, so the use case for single file deployment seem much weaker. And I imagine that there are technical reasons for not bundling everything in a giant .js file.

Comment: @JonasH i'm not really building a web application in .NET so much as I just want to export some business logic and algorithms for use in various web pages. OpenCV does this with OpenCV.js which has all the wasm (as base64) and other dependencies bundled in a single file that can be dropped into individual web pages(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)